# How to use a rowcount in select statement to modify the query to fetch data for 10 days , if rowcount is 0 for 5 days?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I need to modify my script using rowcount to check if the data in table or not?. Here, i write the query to select a data for last 5 days from current system date. But sometimes there is no data in table for 5 days. So i need to fetch for 10 day or more.

```
Query:

Select ep.ENTERPRISE_NAME||'|'||s.id||'|'||s.SUBMISSION_DATE||'|'||E.VALUE
from JOB_SUMMARY_EXT e, ob_summary s, enterprise ep
where e.id = s.id and e.name_res_key = 'Model'
and s.job_id in (select id from job_summary where
trunc(start_date) > trunc(sysdate) -10 and service_name ='Model2' )
```

I don't know how to modify my Query using rowcount. If rowcount is 0 then i want select data for 10 days.Otherwise it should to fetch for 5 days automatically. I want this to be done as single query.

Comment: What's the version of database?.You mean count from 5 or 10 days in sub query (select id from job_summary)?

Comment: Oracle version:12.1.0.2.0.yeah..if count is equal to 0, query should fetch data for 10 days otherwise it fetch data for 5 days

Comment: count based on what? .Can you post count select statement?

Answer (score 1):

It looks that you want to select the last 5 "days" from that table. So, why would you *anchor* to `SYSDATE` if there aren't rows for each of those days? I'd suggest another approach: literally, select last 5 days. Here's how.

As I don't have your tables, I'm using Scott's `EMP` table which contains information about employees. It is an ancient one so `HIREDATE` column is set to 1980s, but never mind that. Sorting employees by `HIREDATE` in descending order shows:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select ename, hiredate from emp order by hiredate desc;

ENAME      HIREDATE
---------- ----------
ADAMS      12.01.1983    1.
SCOTT      09.12.1982    2.
MILLER     23.01.1982    3.
FORD       03.12.1981    4.
JAMES      03.12.1981    4.
KING       17.11.1981    5.   --> I want to fetch rows up to KING
MARTIN     28.09.1981
TURNER     08.09.1981
CLARK      09.06.1981
BLAKE      01.05.1981
JONES      02.04.1981
WARD       22.02.1981
ALLEN      20.02.1981
SMITH      17.12.1980

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

As you can see, the 4th date is shared by two employees so I want to include them both. `DENSE_RANK` analytic function helps:

```
SQL> with last5 as
  2    (select ename,
  3            job,
  4            sal,
  5            hiredate,
  6            dense_rank() over (order by hiredate desc) rnk
  7     from emp
  8    )
  9  select ename, job, sal, hiredate
 10  from last5
 11  where rnk <= 5;

ENAME      JOB              SAL HIREDATE
---------- --------- ---------- ----------
ADAMS      CLERK           1100 12.01.1983
SCOTT      ANALYST         3000 09.12.1982
MILLER     CLERK           1300 23.01.1982
JAMES      CLERK            950 03.12.1981
FORD       ANALYST         3000 03.12.1981
KING       PRESIDENT       5000 17.11.1981

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

What does it do? The `LAST5` CTE sorts employees (as above), `DENSE_RANK` ranks them; finally, the last `SELECT` (which begins at line #9) fetches desired rows.

---

In your case, that might look like this:

```
with last5 as
  (select id,
          dense_rank() over (order by start_date desc) rnk
   from job_summary
   where service_name = 'Model2'
  )
select ep.enterprise_name, 
       s.id, 
       s.submission_date, 
       e.value
from job_summary_ext e 
  join ob_summary s on e.id = s.id
  join last5 t on t.id = s.id
  join enterprise ep on <you're missing join condition for this table>
where e.name_res_key = 'Model';
```

Note that you're missing join condition for the `ENTERPRISE` table; if that's really so, no problem - you'd use `cross join` for that table, but I somehow doubt that you want that.

Finally, as you use SQL*Plus, perhaps you don't need to concatenate all columns and separate them by the pipe `|` sign - set it as a column separator, e.g.

```
SQL> set colsep '|'
SQL>
SQL> select deptno, dname, loc from dept;

    DEPTNO|DNAME         |LOC
----------|--------------|-------------
        10|ACCOUNTING    |NEW YORK
        20|RESEARCH      |DALLAS
        30|SALES         |CHICAGO
        40|OPERATIONS    |BOSTON

SQL>
```

---

If you want to

- return 10 last days if `select count(*)` returns 0, or
- return 5 last days if `select count(*)` returns a positive number

then something like this might help (again based on Scott's EMP table):

```
with 
tcnt as
  -- count number of rows; use your own requirement, I'm checking
  -- whether someone got hired today. In Scott's EMP table, nobody was
  -- so CNT = 0
  (select count(*) cnt
   from emp 
   where hiredate >= trunc(sysdate)
  )
select e.ename, e.job, e.sal, e.hiredate
from emp e cross join tcnt c
where e.hiredate >= case when c.cnt = 0 then trunc(sysdate) - 10
                         else                trunc(sysdate) -  5
                    end;
```

Apply it to your tables; I don't know which of those 3 tables' `count` you want to check.

Comment: I want to use if else condition here. If my row count is equal to 0 than i  have fetch data for 10 days. Else , i have to fetch 5 days

Comment: Is there any to way to add if else condition in select statement?

Comment: In SQL, you can't have IF-THEN-ELSE. But, you can have CASE. I added some more code. Have a look, please.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to add in comments but it was too long for comments and  Not clear on count based on but here is case in where clause substitute your count statement with nvl function

```
 SELECT ep.ENTERPRISE_NAME||'|'||s.id||'|'||s.SUBMISSION_DATE||'|'||E.VALUE
    FROM JOB_SUMMARY_EXT e,
         ob_summary s,
         enterprise ep
    WHERE e.id = s.id
      AND e.name_res_key = 'Model'
      AND s.job_id IN
        (SELECT id
         FROM job_summary
         WHERE service='Model'
           AND trunc(start_date) > 
          CASE WHEN
              (WRITE your SELECT COUNT criteria WITH NVL FUNCTION)<=0 THEN 
                 trunc(sysdate) -10 
               ELSE trunc(sysdate)-5 
           END )
```